# How to Upsert an Object in MongoDB correctly?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, javascript-objects

I'm trying to Upsert Entries in my MongoDB. The Structure of all Objects is:

```
{
ids: { id_1: '7264432' },
ranktime:
   [ { pos: '4',
       date: '000' } ],
name: 'Strength',
version: 'Hi',
artist: 'Example'
}
```

Now I want to Upsert the `ids` Object with an Object like:

```
response[i] = {
ids: { id_2: '55551123' },
ranktime:
   [ { pos: '4',
       date: '000' } ],
name: 'Strength',
version: 'Hi',
artist: 'Example'
}
```

resulting in:

```
{
ids: { id_1: '7264432', id_2: '55551123' },
ranktime:
   [ { pos: '4',
       date: '000' } ],
name: 'Strength',
version: 'Hi',
artist: 'Example'
}
```

I'm selecting the document uniquely with:

```
collection.updateMany(
{ $and: [{name: response[i].name}, {version: response[i].version}, {artist: response[i].artist}}]} ,
{
  $set: {ids:  response[i].ids}
},
{upsert: true},
})
```

but all that happens, if that the ids field is being overwritten with the new value instead of just adding the new value. 
Is there any solution with MongoDB methods to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do. For some reason I had to pass the $set as a pipeline. So this is **not working**

```
collection.updateMany(
{ $and: [{name: response[i].name}, {version: response[i].version}, {artist: response[i].artist}}]}
{
  $set: {ids:  response[i].ids}
},
{upsert: true},
})
```

but this is **working**

```
collection.updateMany(
{ $and: [{name: response[i].name}, {version: response[i].version}, {artist: response[i].artist}}]}
[{
  $set: {ids:  response[i].ids}
}]
})
```

It's also not an upsert if I do it this way. Can anyone explain this maybe?

Comment: First a vocabulary correction "upsert" means to create a new document and insert into the collection via an update statement.  Modifying an existing document is "update", adding an additional value to an array while updating is usually referred to as "push".

Comment: The first one didn't work because you have `{upsert: true}` included in the second argument, which is the update.  That is an option that should go in a third argument to `updateMany`.  Both of these statements will completely replace the `ids` field with the new value, was that your intent?

Comment: My intent was to add only new key:values pairs and leave the existing untouched. The working version of my "solution" does this, by adding the [] brackets to my set statement. If i don't add the [] brackets, my `ids` field will be replaced without only adding new ones

Comment: Strange, when I test using `[{$set...}]` it replaces the field.

Comment: Yes, really strange. I just tried it again. If I set the [] brackets, the new object is just added, if i don't set them, the field is replaced. Is it a version Issue? I'm running on 4.2.5